# Deformations of a string loop of given length?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, geometry, geometric-topology

Given a flexible string of length that crosses at a point, how is it possible to describe all possible deformations of it?

For instance the loop in the following picture.

[image]

I’m guessing that this involves topology and linear algebra, but I’m not sure where to start.  I would like to consider the case of 2D and 3D.

Comment: Are you seeking a description more qualitatively different from something like "the space of all mappings from a circle into the plane/space"?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang what you quoted is what I’m seeking in set theoretic language. The circle needs to have a given length

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I searched for your quote online but found no match. Do you have any guidance on finding the resources to describe this?

Comment: The quoted phrase was more a qualitative sample than a literal search term: At the requested level of generality there's not much to say. You might look into "homotopy" or "isotopy" as ways of making "deformation" precise. Regarding length, there's an issue of whether the total length alone needs to be constant, or whether you want to model deformation of a flexible but inelastic loop (which is a stronger condition).